# How to draw routes in Rails engine gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm having a lot of trouble drawing routes in an engine gem I'm building. No idea what I'm doing wrong...I must have tried a half dozen different things already. Currently my gem looks like this:

Gem structure:

```
├── Gemfile
├── MIT-LICENSE
├── README.md
├── app
│   └── controllers
│       └── rails_dribbble_oauth
│           └── main_controller.rb
├── config
│   └── routes.rb
├── lib
│   ├── rails_dribbble_oauth
│   │   ├── engine.rb
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── rails_dribbble_oauth.rb
└── rails_dribbble_oauth.gemspec
```

/app/controllers/rails_dribbble_oauth/main_controller.rb:

```
module RailsDribbbleOauth
  class MainController < ::ApplicationController
    # some instance methods
  end
end
```

/lib/rails_dribbble_oauth/engine.rb:

```
module RailsDribbbleOauth
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace :RailsDribbbleOauth
  end
end
```

lib/rails_dribbble_oauth.rb:

```
require "rails_dribbble_oauth/engine"

module RailsDribbbleOauth
end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'request',     to: 'main#request',  as: "dribbble_oauth_request"
    get 'callback',    to: 'main#passthru', as: "dribbble_callback"
end
```

When I add this into my test app and run rake routes, none of the routes defined in the gem appear in my app.

I've also tried mounting it by using `RailsDribbbleOauth::Engine.routes.draw`, then adding `mount RailsDribbbleOauth::Engine, at: '/dribbble'` into my test app, but that's resulted in `NameError: uninitialized constant RailsDribbbleOauth::Engine`.

Any help is really appreciated, thank you.

Edit: test app's Gemfile does include the gem. Gem is currently being developed within the test app at `lib/engines/rails_dribbble_oauth`. From test app's Gemfile: `gem 'rails-dribbble-oauth', path: 'lib/engines/rails_dribbble_oauth'`. Still, `rake routes` does not yield any routes defined in the gem.

Comment: are you adding the engine to the applications Gemfile, e.g. `gem 'rails_dribble_oauth', path: 'engines/rails_dribble_oauth`? If so any models you have defined in the engine should be accessible from `rails console`.

Comment: Thanks Kris. I am not defining any models in my gem. Yes, gemfile is in the main application's Gemfile: `gem 'rails-dribbble-oauth', path: 'lib/engines/rails_dribbble_oauth'`.

Comment: Have you tried moving it out of lib in to RAILS_ROOT/engines, a long shot but sometimes lib is in the LOAD_PATH and Rails might think the files map to classes in a `Lib::` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Moved the gem and changed the path in the Gemfile, but no changes in `rake routes`.

Comment: I don't think you error has anything to do with how you are defining you routes, but that the engine, for whatever reason, is not being loaded by the parent app. This is evident by `uninitialized constant RailsDribbbleOauth::Engine`, you need to fix that first. Just adding the engine, provided it was generated by `rails plugin`, should mean it gets required and integrated in to the parent app. Is there a file `lib/rails_dribbble_oauth/engine.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add the engine to the test applications `Gemfile`, for example:

```
# if the engines in at RAILS_ROOT/engines
gem 'rails_dribble_oauth', path: 'engines/rails_dribble_oauth'

# somewhere else
gem 'rails_dribble_oauth', path: '~/dev/rails_dribble_oauth'
```

Comment: Thanks for input. My gemfile in the test app already has the gem, which is being developed in that test app's lib folder. From the gemfile: `gem 'rails-dribbble-oauth', path: 'lib/engines/rails_dribbble_oauth'`.